# Flex box white space issue with different height component

Tags: vue.js, flexbox, vuetify.js

I need other components to take over the white space [Click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Ez4.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <v-card class="d-flex" color="grey lighten-2" flat height="100" tile>
        <v-card class="pa-2 ma-2" outlined tile>
          flex item
        </v-card>

        <v-card class="pa-2 ma-2 align-self-start" outlined tile>
          Aligned start
        </v-card>

        <v-card class="pa-2 ma-2" outlined tile>
          flex item
        </v-card>
      </v-card>

      <v-card class="d-flex mb-6" color="grey lighten-2" flat height="100" tile>
        <v-card class="pa-2 ma-2" outlined tile>
          flex item
        </v-card>

        <v-card class="pa-2 ma-2 align-self-stretch" outlined tile>
          Aligned stretch
        </v-card>

        <v-card class="pa-2 ma-2" outlined tile>
          flex item
        </v-card>
      </v-card>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```